# Teamcity Custom Script Log Output

Tags: teamcity

I use a very basic *Custom Script* in TeamCity 7.0.3 which uses Visual Studio 2010 to build a solution and its installers.

The build was failing and the only relevant error in the TeamCity Build Log is

> [13:17:13]Process exited with code 1

When I run the same script from the console, I get a lot of helpful errors about why the build failed.

How can I get TeamCity to include the errors from devenv.exe?

Comment: Did you open the log file itself and not just look for info on the build tab ?

Comment: Just looking on the build tab.

Comment: Well that's just an overview, on the upper right of the page you should be able to download the build log.  Open that up and see if you get the more detailed trace.

Answer (score 6):

You need to report back the additional info to TeamCity in a way it can interpret.

Look at this article to see how to do it:

http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity

For a basic example:

> You can report messages for build log in the following way:
>
> `##teamcity[message text='<message text>' errorDetails='<error details>' status='<status value>']`

Comment: from the link, I believe "Reporting Build Status" is the important bit for the OP

Comment: Thanks for this. Link to documentation for latest version: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity